# How to source a file in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I have a maven project in Intellij Idea. For a dependency jar, I have given a system path which contains a variable. This variable will be available only if I source a certain file, say "~/dir1/file1". Because of this, Intellij is unable to find the jar and is showing an error there. So, how do I source this file in Intellij? I can't manually replace the path for that variable because there are many such variables and the value of the variables may differ based on the version of "~/dir1/file1" file.

Please don't suggest to source the file before starting Intellij, because I don't start Intellij from terminal, but from Launchpad. Or is sourcing in a terminal and then starting Intellij from terminal, the only way to go?

**Edit 1**: I'm running Intellij Community Edition on Mac Book Pro

Answer (score 4):

You can add [start up tasks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/startup-tasks.html).

Create a bash script for your files. You can add "bash" start up task (many other option also available like ant,grunt,npm if you have those plugins installed - but for our use case just a bash would do)

On creating new bash task:

[image: create startup task]

You can specify the location of the script of the .sh file in the configuration to be executed every-time on startup:

[image: new task]

Comment: I added a bash startup task. When Intellij starts, it is sourcing that specified file. But in pom.xml, systemPath, Intellij is not recognising the environment variable. I tried using other environment variables such as `HOME`, it is working (`env.HOME`). Also in startup script, I'm printing all environment variables using `printenv` before and after sourcing. After sourcing, it is printing all my desired variables, but Intellij is not recognising

Comment: Did you try setting environment variables in the config?

Comment: Which config?
Also, I tried exporting a variable in the startup script. Even that variable is not recognised by Intellij in systemPath in pom.xml

Comment: In the second screenshot above - there is a way to give environment variables? (I tried for grunt task. but for bash - program arguments support is also there which should help if env variables are not being passed)

Comment: Yes. I tried setting the environment variable there. Didn't work.